# How to link Google Custom Search Engine with Google Analytics 4?

Tags: google, google-analytics, search-results

I use Google Custom Search Engine (a.k.a. Google Programmable Search Engine) on a website. I have added a search box to a page and search results are displayed on another page (the URL of search results page contains the searched term like this: `www.example.com/search?q=PRODUCT`)

I would like to set up Google Analytics 4 to generate a report of the most frequently searched terms.

Is it possible to configure GA4 to generate such reports automatically (like it was possible with UA)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Set up a programmable search engine**

- Create a Google Programmable Search Engine for your website.
- Choose a search engine type that displays search results on your own website with a query parameter name embedded in the url (e.g. "?q=").
- Add the search engine's codes to your site.

**Set up Google Analytics 4**

- Create a new GA4 property.
- Enable "Enhanced measurement" and make sure capturing "Site Search" is turned on.
- Add GA4 code to your website or add GA4 to your website with Google Tag Manager ( recommended ).
- From now on, sites searches on your website get recorded by Google Analytics.

**See the results**

*( It may take 24-48h hours to get the results in Google Analytics after the first search. )*

- Open the "Exploration" tab on Google Analytics.
- Create a new "Free From".
- Click on the plus sign to create a new "Dimension" and choose "Site Search".
- Add "Site Search" to the "Rows" panel.
- Add "Event Count" to the "Values" panel.